# Receiving Can BUS frame Qt and PeakCan USB adapter

Tags: can-bus

I want to receive Can Bus frame from Qt with a PeakCan USB adapter from Peak System. At the moment I can write on the bus and it works well, I check with PCAN View but my problem is in the reading process.

When I transmit datas with PCAN View my reading slot doesn't occure although I do the connect.

This is my class constructor and the member m_device is QCanBusDevice type :

```
m_device = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice("peakcan", "usb0");
m_device->connectDevice()
connect(m_device, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, this, &BusCan::onFramesReceived);
```

And now my slot for reading Can Bus frames :

```
void BusCan::onFramesReceived() {
    qDebug() << "[Frame received] !";
}
```

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with my pcan-dongle. I did not change anything of your calls beside the class names etc.

In order to get the signal emitted, you have to ensure that

- you are running a `QCoreApplication` or `QApplication`
- your class `BusCan` has to inherit `QObject` and contain the `Q_OBJECT`-macro.

If it still does not work, you can make `QCanBus` show verbose logging as described in the docs:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialbus-index.html

You also can check `error()` and `errorString()` from your `QCanBusDevice`